# Difference between QObject::connect() and connect()

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qobject

I am new to Qt and I want to try to understand it better.

I know from an inheritance perspective that a **QMainWindow** is derived from **QObject.** (Directly/Indirectly)

This allows for us to connect signals to slots in the following ways within the QMainWindow:

`

```
1- QObject::connect(sender, &QObject::signal, this, &MyObject::slot);
2- connect(sender, &QObject::signal, this, &MyObject::slot);
```

`

Even tough both ways are a possibility, I never understood what the major differences between them are.

Here are my questions:

1- Which method is more performant and why?

2- Why do programmers sometimes use one over the other?

I used both of these methods and they both seem to work similarly.

Comment: When the class has multiple inheritance say, from ClassA and ClassB then we can still resolve the base for the method to call like `ClassA::method(). Also certain variations of 6 connect() method belonging to QObject are static so it makes sense to designate call as static then: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#connect-4

Comment: `I used both of these methods and they both seem to work similarly.` - and they also call exactly the same function in the end.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand the static reason. 

However, what would be the reason to use one over another? 

As an example, let's say I am currently in the implementation file of my QMainWindow class (mainwindow.cpp). Why would I every use QObject::connect() instead of simply calling connect()?

Comment: You may not need to use `QObject::` to get to the base class if you call `connect()` from its method when you connect to its own signal. And you may need to use `QObject::` when you call it to connect the signal from the other object to some slot of of this or third object.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following code.

```cpp
class Foo { 
  static void fn(); 
};
class Bar: public Foo {
  void bar() {
    // 1
  }
};
void main() {
  // 2
}
```

If you want to call `Foo::fn()` at `1`, you can just write `fn();` since static functions is "visible" inside methods in derived classes, you can also write `Foo::fn()` and it will do exactly the same. If you want to call it at `2`, you can only use full name `Foo::fn()`.